# Wordpress template installation error

Tags: wordpress

I have a php template downloaded from a site.But when i copied all files to my public_html folder and tried to install the site it is showing an error can u help me .It is showing as "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/u116779892/public_html/index.php on line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress templates should be placed in `public_html/wp-content/themes/<theme_name>/`. So if your theme is called 'mytheme' it would be `public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/`.

Now you're overriding the core index.php (the theme also has a file called index.php). You can better re-install wordpress, as you probably messed up a lot now

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Wordpress theme or just a plain PHP template you installed?

It seems some files got overwritten (get_header() doesn't appear in Wordpress' index.php)

so I recommend you to recover or reinstall the Wordpress.

After that, put the files(if it is a Wordpress theme) to

/home/u116779892/public_html/wp-content/themes/[themename]/